# Import R data into Python problem with NA and data.table

Tags: python, r, import, data.table, export

I want to import a `data.table` from R saved using `saveRDS` into python. I found the package in python `pyreadr`that works fine, but then it did not work for some `data.table` of mine which had missing. I was not able to find a similiar questions and I am pretty new to python.

MWE to create some data in R

```
library(data.table)    
df<-data.table(Name="Heilbronn", lon=9.208, lat=49.124, type=c(NA, "bus_station"), north=c(NA, 4.5))
saveRDS(df,"test_dt.r")
saveRDS(na.omit(df),"test_dt_naomit.r")
df<-data.frame(Name="Heilbronn", lon=9.208, lat=49.124, type=c(NA, "bus_station"), north=c(NA, 4.5))
saveRDS(df,"test_df.r")
```

So I then try to read this in in python

```
import pyreadr
pyreadr.read_r("test_dt.r")
```

Does not work and I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-57-383514f95bcb>", line 1, in <module>
    result = pyreadr.read_r("../test.r")

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyreadr\pyreadr.py", line 47, in read_r
    parser.parse(path)

  File "pyreadr\librdata.pyx", line 117, in pyreadr.librdata.Parser.parse

  File "pyreadr\librdata.pyx", line 142, in pyreadr.librdata.Parser.parse

LibrdataError: Unable to allocate memory
```

The following two work and I am assuming because in the first case ther is no `NA` and in the second it is only a `data.frame`

```
pyreadr.read_r("test_dt_naomit.r")
pyreadr.read_r("test_df.r")
```

Comment: Please see the [known limitations](https://github.com/ofajardo/pyreadr#known-limitations) of pyreadr: `Objects that depend on non base R packages cannot be read.` If they are willing to support data.table's you might want to create a [feature request](https://github.com/ofajardo/pyreadr/issues).

Comment: I have the same problem with the data frames, but I could not replicate the problem with a MWE

Comment: If the problem exists for data.frames you might want to file an issue on GitHub.

Comment: I suggests to use `csv` format instead. You can write it fast from R with `data.table::fwrite` and read it fast in python using python's `datatable` `fread`, and then convert to pandas if needed. Will be much faster than trying to read csv with pandas.

Comment: Thx this is what I actually have done in the meantime. It would have been nice to be ablte to use the `saveRDS` function because I have been storing all data like this within my R project. I ll try the functions you proposed. For my project spead and data size is probably not an issue